# Unable to get doc id in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the doc id of each data entry upon click to delete that specific record, but upon checking it is only showing id of the first entry made in the Firebase.

```
const deleteRecord = () => {
  db.collection("records").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // console.log(doc.id)
      let recToDel = document.querySelectorAll(".records")
      for (let toDelRecord of recToDel) {
        toDelRecord.onclick = () => {
          console.log(doc.id)
        }
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are listening to all records documents but then looping over recToDel for every document.

Comment: basically I want to get the doc.id of the record I am clicking so that I can delete it

Comment: There's no need to query to do that again... can you share the code that fetches and shows the records on screen at first place? There you can store doc id in attributes or something.

Answer (score 1):

The loops are nested, so the last iteration of the `querySnapshot.forEach` loop is the one that sets the same doc.id for every `recToDel` dom element.

Fix by looping just one collection and indexing into the other...

```
    let recToDel = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".records"));
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc, index) => {
      if (index < recToDel.length) {
        let toDelRecord = recToDel[index];
        toDelRecord.onclick = () => {
          console.log(doc.id)
        }
      }
    });
```

If there are fewer `.records` elements than there are docs, some won't be assigned.

Doing this `onSnapshot` will cause these assignments to be made every time the collection changes, including on deletes.  If that's not your intention, fix by changing to `get()`.